# Free SQL test data generator

Tags: windows, gratis, sql-server, sql

I'm searching for a tool to generate SQL test data.

What I'm looking for exactly should

1. Be gratis
2. Generate test data from Regex
3. Be compatible with Microsoft SQL Server (compatibility with MySQL and others is a plus)
4. Make direct connections with the database server
5. Run on Windows

Something like [RedGate SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) but it should be free.

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/what-tools-are-there-to-generate-test-data-for-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Mockaroo.com](http://mockaroo.com/). It does generally what you are looking for and i think it should be able to get the job done. Here is what it can do.

- generate test data(up to 1000 rows)
- it generates very realistic data
- you can download the data in the form of a sql file

It does not make a direct connection to the database. It also cannot generate data with Regex. You can however choose from over 89 types of different data such as IP addresses names addresses and email addresses. It can only generate data for only 1000 rows though. You can however get a paid plan which will give you up to 10 million rows and faster speeds. You though have to run the SQL file on the database. This should not be so hard but it can be time consuming. Another downside is that if you are using an id column as your primary key then the Mockaroo.com will generate the data starting from id 0. There may be a setting that allows you to change this but I could not find it. So this may be a problem if you already have data in your SQL database. If you need an application to run the .sql files that Mockaroo.com generates i developed a simple program to do it for you. You can download the program [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DLfOmIkFD7TTR6V19xd0NmSDA/view?usp=sharing).